# Manipulating an image of a face with Flash and AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, image-processing

everyone. This isn't as much of an specific technical question as it is about asking for some guidance on which steps should I follow.

The thing is I haven't worked with Flash in general for over a year and I'm very rusty, but now, here at work, I need to create an app that takes a picture, detects the face in said picture and then applies a certain animation effect. For example a slap to the face, so the detected face would shake from side-to-side or maybe something similar to the Fatify app, where it takes the pic, makes the person look fat and then you can touch it anywhere to see it animate. You get the idea.

So, my main problem is, that even after doing some extensive research, I'm still not clear on what the best method is or which would be the best tools to accomplish the animation effects on the detected face. I have read about Joa Ebert's Image Processing Library, but that seems to have been forgotten for quite a while and seeing as I have been out of the loop from the world of Flash for quite a while, I don't know if there's any novelty that could be what I'm looking for. I have also looked at countless image manipulation blog posts and tutorials, but most of it is simple stuff that doesn't really apply to what I need.

So, in summary, I would really apreciate it if anyone could point me to resources or topics that I should look into, that might prove useful for what I need to accomplish.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to take a look at PixelBender. It's not the answer to this and would likely make this project much more difficult to do, but the performance gains you would get from it may be well worth it. Again, it's a pain to use but it is very powerful and takes a lot of the load off Flash itself to do the image manipulations.

Comment: There is actually a pixel blender version of OpenCV

Comment: @FlavorScape Really? That's pretty awesome. OpenCV is pretty powerful, but nothing can beat the speed that PixelBender provides.

Comment: Thank you, both. I'm going to take a look at both OpenCV and PixelBender and try to go from here.

Comment: Hm, not that magical solution. I make a correction, looks like some people are just compiling the C++ OpenCV lib into Flash using Alchemy. http://www.scribd.com/doc/77861351/Building-OpenCV-Using-Alchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using OpenCV. The library is quite extensive and has been ported to operate in many languages. OpenCV has an api for facial tracking. We've used it in our studio before for simple face tracking games.

These links are kind of dated, but should put you on the right track.

http://www.francois-tarlier.com/blog/marilena-opencv-port-to-actionscript-3-as3-flash/

http://www.marcpelland.com/2009/03/16/face-detection-opencv-in-as3/